# Controlling concurrent logins to an application

Tags: java, session, tomcat, application-server

I want to control number of users that can be login into my application at a time. For example I want to allow only 10  users to use my application at a time. If 11'th user tries to login to use my application I want to show him some message showing " All resources are busy. Try after some time.".

How can I do this in a java based application servers?

-Narendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increment a counter each time a user logs in. Decrement it each time a user logs out, and each time the HttpSession of a logged in user is destroyed (by using an [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html)).

When a user logs in and the counter is at 10, then refuse to log him in.

I really don't knwow why you would want to do that, though. It makes no sense to me.